# Linux Kernel Threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, kernel

So I'm working on a linux Kernel module which requires an infinite waiting loop in a separate thread initiated by kthread. The following is the function run by kthread, and train.queue_mutex is a mutex initialized before kthread (via mutex_init(&train.queue_mutex))

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it locks the kernel.  My thinking is that between the mdelay and the schedule() every iteration, other processes should get CPU time.

```
 int train_thread(void *param)
    {
            while (!train.is_deactivating)
            {
                    mutex_lock_interruptible(&train.queue_mutex);
                    while (train.num_waiting > 0)
                    {
                        int five_foward = (train.stop + 5) % 10;
                        int five_back = (train.stop - 5) % 10;
                        int i = train.stop;
                        int max_count = 0;
                        int max_count_index = 0;

                        for (;i != five_foward; i = (i + 1) % 10)
                        {
                                int count = robots_count(train.waiting[i]);
                                if (count > max_count)
                                {
                                        max_count_index = i;
                                        max_count       = count;
                                }
                        }


                        for (i = train.stop ;i != five_back; i = (i - 1) % 10)
                        {
                                int count = robots_count(train.waiting[i]);
                                if (count > max_count)
                                {
                                        max_count_index = i;
                                        max_count       = count;
                                }
                        }

                        // Should have max_count_index set to index of stop with the most bots
                        printk("Most bots %d at stop %d\n", max_count, max_count_index);
                        mutex_unlock(&train.queue_mutex);
                        schedule();
                        mutex_lock_interruptible(&train.queue_mutex);
                }
                mutex_unlock(&train.queue_mutex);
                mdelay(10);
        }

        train.is_active = 0;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "the schedule() every found" mean?

Comment: I think that was meant to say "round" - edited.

Comment: Just to check, did you put in print statements to make sure one of your for loops isn't infinite looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  for (i = train.stop ;i != five_back; i = (i - 1) % 10)
>  {
>     int count = robots_count(train.waiting[i]);
> ```

When i == 1, you have five_back negative and  effectively `robots_count(train.waiting[-1);` after 2 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've fixed the logic problem pointed out by bestsss you still have the problem that `mdelay()` is a busy-wait, which does not release the CPU. You should consider `schedule_timeout()` or `msleep`. Take a look in [Linux Device Drivers](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-3.shtml) for more details.